# Row orthonormal equivalent to column orthonormal (Lorentzian inner product)

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a book on relativity and this was left as an exercise: Let $M$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix of real numbers. Suppose that its row space forms an orthonormal basis given a [Lorentzian inner product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianInnerProduct.html), prove that its column space forms an orthonormal basis as well.

I am aware of the claim in the case of ordinary dot product, but after a while still can’t replicate the idea of the proof ($AA^T=I$) here. Any help would be appreciated:)

PS: Also I’m just curious if this would hold for any symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form (which the book simply calls an inner product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B \in GL_4\big(\mathbb R\big)$
$D := \begin{bmatrix}
I_3 & \mathbf 0 \\ 
\mathbf 0  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$B^TDB = D \longrightarrow (B^TD)(BD) = I=(BD)(B^TD)\longrightarrow BDB^T = D $
where I used the fact that $D$ is involutive, and inverses commute
so $B$ and $B^T$ are in the Lorentz group.

Comment: Thanks, that’s really helpful.